# jekyll installation ubuntu: gem verification

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, installation, jekyll

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-deploy-jekyll-blogs-with-git) that allows to host Jekyll on my droplet. I have everything working on my machine, now to get everything set up on digital ocean.

```
apt-get install git-core
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby=2.0.0
```

So far so good:

```
# sudo gem install jekyll
Successfully installed jekyll-1.3.0
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for jekyll-1.3.0...
Installing RDoc documentation for jekyll-1.3.0...
```

Then I get an error when I try to do something with jekyll:

```
root@jackrabbit:~# jekyll
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find jekyll (>= 0)    amongst [bundler-1.3.5, bundler-unload-1.0.2, executable-hooks-1.2.6, liquid-2.5.4, rake-    10.1.0, rubygems-bundler-1.4.2, rvm-1.11.3.8] (Gem::LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:22:in `<main>'
```

I checked the gem list:

```
root@jackrabbit:~# gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.0)
bundler (1.3.5)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
executable-hooks (1.2.6)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.7.7)
liquid (2.5.4)
minitest (4.3.2)
psych (2.0.0)
rake (10.1.0, 0.9.6)
rdoc (4.0.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.2)
rvm (1.11.3.8)
test-unit (2.0.0.0)
```

And I can see that jekyll is not there. What have I done wrong? Is there another way to make sure that jekyll is installed properly on ubuntu?

EDIT:

When re-installing jekyll, I now get this new error:

```
root@jackrabbit:~# gem install jekyll
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby extconf.rb

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/fast-stemmer-1.0.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/fast-stemmer-1.0.2/ext/gem_make.out
```

This might be helpful to understand the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jekyll works just fine with the ubuntu ruby 1.9.3

```
# for Ubuntu 12.04
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1 ruby1.9.1-dev \
  rubygems1.9.1 irb1.9.1 ri1.9.1 rdoc1.9.1 \
  build-essential libopenssl-ruby1.9.1 libssl-dev zlib1g-dev

# for Ubuntu 14.04
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ruby ruby1.9.1-dev ri1.9.1 node-js
```

Then you just have to install Jekyll

```
sudo gem install bundler
sudo gem install jekyll
```

Comment: you are using a different ruby version but this seems to work.